# writing errors in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-typescript

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    const tsResult = tsConfig.src()
        .pipe(tsConfig());
    tsResult.on('error', function (err) {
        fs.writeFileSync('errors.txt', err.stack)
    });
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I am using this gulp task to catch the error and write it in the errors file but I get the error like this "Error: TypeScript: Compilation failed" but I need detail about the error and stack details in the error src file

I have file name index.ts in that i have specified some error like this:

> `Cannot find name 'sdfdf'.`

I want this error to be write in the error file